# How to regress all rows with the same date on a specific value?

Tags: r, linear-regression, finance

I'm new using R. I have the following sample dataset:

```
> head(abn)
       Dates  DTM   YTM
1 2010-09-28 1133 2.965
2 2010-09-28 1834 3.613
3 2010-09-29 1132 2.994
4 2010-09-29 1833 3.595
5 2010-09-30 1131 3.026
6 2010-09-30 1832 3.590
```

The observations are several bond values on an observation period from 2010-2016. My data set is composed of multiple bonds with maturities between 1-15 years (260-3900 business days as depicted in the dataset). 
DTM stands for days to maturity and YTM for yield to maturity.

My goal is to construct a synthetic bond with a maturity of 5 years for each day. Therefore I need to make a regression and find the YTM value for the DTM value of 1300, which is exactly 5 years.

Plot of all bonds on all dates
[image]

```
> plot(dtm, ytm, xlab = "Days to maturity", ylab = "Yield to maturity")
> abline(lm (ytm~dtm), col="red")
```

I plotted all the bonds on all dates in one regression. I need to get the value of the y-axis at x=1300. However I need to have this information for every date separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)
newval <- data.frame(DTM=1300) #predict.lm likes new values in a dataframe
abn5y <- abn %>% group_by(Dates) %>% 
                 summarise(Y5=predict(lm(YTM ~ DTM), newval))

abn5y
       Dates       Y5
       <chr>    <dbl>
1 2010-09-28 3.119374
2 2010-09-29 3.138034
3 2010-09-30 3.161971
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. However i got an error message:


 newval <- data.frame(DTM=1300) #predict.lm likes new values in a dataframe
> abn5y <- abn %>% group_by(Dates) %>% 
+     summarise(Y5=predict(lm(YTM ~ DTM), newval))
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: It sounds like you haven't loaded `dplyr`

Comment: I tried loading it as follows:

> library(dplyr)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  es gibt kein Paket namens ‘DBI’
In addition: Warning message:
Paket ‘dplyr’ wurde unter R Version 3.2.5 erstellt 
Error: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘dplyr’ fehlgeschlagen


Then I used this:

> install.packages("dplyr")

This one worked to download, but however the code does not work unfortunately.

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get an error message, or does it produce the wrong answer?

Comment: I had to do a different style to download the "dplyr" package, however it finally worked now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)
abn<-read.csv("abn.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
dfs<-dlply(abn,.(Dates))

dailyYTM<-c()

for (i in unique(abn$Dates)){
    df<-dfs[[grep(i,names(dfs))]]
    model<-lm(df$YTM~df$DTM)
    dailyYTM[i]<-model$coefficients[1]+model$coefficients[2]*1300
}
```

not the most efficient but I think will do the trick.dailyYTM is the result